# Setting g++ compiler flags for debugging

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following c++ code

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int *pa = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i!=n; ++i) pa[i] = 0;
    cout << pa[n] << endl;
    delete[] pa;
}
```

Actually, this piece of code can be compiled by g++ and run, however, with a wrong result since `pa[n]` is out of the array bound.

My question is: is it possible to set some debugger flags for g++ at the compiling stage so that the compiler can prompt me of this? Additionally, what're the normal flags setting for debugging in g++?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with [std::array::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [std::vector::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually I am programming a scientific code, so efficiency is very important to me. So I am trying to avoid using the container defined in STL.

Comment: @jwyan1126 I bet the STL containers are faster than your code.

Comment: @melpomene I know STL container is very efficient and safe to use. But will it even faster than barely manipulating the array in C++? Because I am thinking to use STL container as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with [`-fsanitize=address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003daddress) can help sometimes; see [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Also, compiling with `-g` and running the program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) finds many dynamic memory errors ([quick intro](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.intro)).

In general, you want to enable basic compiler warnings. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2` is a good start. `-O2` is technically for optimization, but sometimes you get more / better warnings with it.

The `-g` flag includes debugging information in the compiled code. If you use a debugger, you'll be able to see the names/values of local variables, line numbers, etc. This can clash with optimizations that reorder or outright remove some code. It is recommended to use `-g -Og` for debugging (not `-O2`).

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot. Thank you very much!